# Test Automation for Android & iOS

Tags: android, python, ios, mobile, automated-tests

I would like to build a test agent for testing Mobile SDKs (for both iOS & Android).

I thought about writing the agent in Python (run on Win Host machine), and the app for the mobile.

I need help with the app itself, it should consider the following for start:

1. **Performance**: It must not not overload the mobile phone.
2. **How to execute app API**: Should I use the adb command? Any other way?

Any BKMs? Recommendations?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows (start activity)

```
import os
cmd = 'adb shell am startservice -n packageName/.ServiceClass'
os.system(cmd)
```